# Can I get acess to my facebook news feed using facebook API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I need to pull my news feed and display it in another app. Can I pull my news feed using Facebook API?

Comment: No there is no API to get newsfeed

Answer (score 3):

**Edit: This answer is the result of misinterpretation of the question, as for the correct answer: No, it isn't possible as the news feed isn't a readable and static object that could be read by the API, it's generated for the user as they use it.**

I myself never used the API, but with a quick search on their docs(https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/feed/) i could find what you need, the question now is what platform are you using the API?

JavaScript example:

```
/* make the API call */
FB.api(
    "/{user-id}/feed",
    function (response) {
      if (response && !response.error) {
        /* handle the result */
      }
    }
);
```

Comment: this gives the posts of a user and posts to his wall. However, I want the news feed of a user.

Comment: @kakino, right, sorry for my misinterpretation, but, as far as i know it won't be possible as the news feed isn't something that could be accessed. The feed is generated as the user reads, it isn't something that could be read and sent by the API.